# overwriting in a .txt file

Tags: visual-c++

I'm writing code with visual c++. My target is writing some double values in a .txt file. The problem is that I'm passing it in a for cicle and everytime there's a file overwrite and so I can see only the last value. (The values of marker1, marker2, marker3 change in every cicle).

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:/Mattia_progetto/LineScannerRealTime/markers.txt");
myfile<<marker1[0]<<"\t"<<marker1[1]<<"\t"<<marker1[2]<<"\t"<<marker2[0]<<"\t"<<marker2[1]<<"\t"<<marker2[3]<<"\t"<<marker3[0]<<"\t"<<marker3[1]<<"\t"<<marker3[2];
myfile.close();
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `ios::app`. Also, learning how to use `for` loop might help you in further coding. Also, use `ofstream` constructor instead of open. Also, buy a goddamn book.

Comment: Have you made sure your data is valid? And do you mean circle or cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `ios::app` as mode flag to `myfile.open()` to append something to the file instead of overwriting the contents.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open

Comment: Please refrain from linking to `cplusplus.com`. That site contains a lot of misleading or plainly wrong information.